# Нет ответа от Aerospike

Tags: c++, aerospike

Пишу свой клиент для Aerospike на C++. Написал простой TCP-клиент, который работает с обычными серверами ([1.1.1.1](http://1.1.1.1) возвращает `Bad request`, что ожидаемо). Однако с Aerospike что-то пошло не так: хоть он и принимает мой запрос (это можно проверить, изменив отправляемое сообщение на бессмыслицу типа `"hello"` - соединение тут же сбросится), но и ответа не отправляет.

Код:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void read_message(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
{
    for (;;)
    {
      boost::array<char, 1> buf;
      boost::system::error_code error;
      size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
      if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
        break;
      else if (error)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);
      std::cout.write(buf.data(), len);
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void send_message(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, std::string message)
{
    boost::array<char, 1024> buf;
    std::copy(message.begin(), message.end(), buf.begin());
    boost::system::error_code error;
    socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf, message.size()), error);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Connecting to socket.." << std::endl;
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 3000);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(ios);
    socket.connect(endpoint);
    std::cout << "Connected to socket. Writing message." << std::endl;
    send_message(socket, "\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006build\nedition\nnode\nservice\nservices\nstatistics\nversion\n\n");
    std::cout << "Wrote message. Reading response." << std::endl;
    read_message(socket);
    std::cout << "Read response. Exiting prigram." << std::endl;
    socket.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Что тут не так? Почему я не могу отловить ответ сервера?

P.S. Aerospike абсолютно точно работает, Python-клиент получает от него корректный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боюсь что вы напоролись на очень глупую ошибку:

```
void send_message(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket, std::string message)
...

    send_message(socket, "\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006build\nedition\nnode\nservice\nservices\nstatistics\nversion\n\n");
```

Как видим: ваша функция принимает строку - все ок (за исключением того, что вы ее содержимое копируете в промежуточный буфер и только потом в сокет). Но что вы передаете в `send_message`? Вы передаете не `std::string`, а `cstring`. Может показаться что это не важно, но не тут то было! `cstring` должен заканчиваться нулевым байтом... который у вас идет третьим по счету. Лучше всего ситуацию продемонстрирует следующий пример:

```cpp
  const char c_str[] = "\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006build\nedition\nnode\nservic"
                     "e\nservices\nstatistics\nversion\n\n";
  std::string str = c_str;
  std::cout << sizeof(c_str) << std::endl; // -> 63
  std::cout << str.size() << std::endl;    // -> 2
```

Почему так? Потому что в данном случае был вызван конструктор, который создает строку из `const char *`, а для него не известен размер, поэтому строка считывается пока не встретится нулевой байт (`cstring`). Но, вы можете сами задать сколько байт считать в строку:

```cpp
std::string str{c_str, sizeof(c_str)};
```

В этом случае в строку будет считано все содержимое литерала. Однако помните: `sizeof` выдаст размер строки только для литерала - если же это `const char *`, то оно выдаст размер указателя.

Вообще вы могли бы сразу выявить проблему проверив что вы пытаетесь отправить - странно что вы этого не сделали.

Comment: Благодарю. Однако это оказалась лишь часть проблемы.

Comment: Фиг знает, как C++ парсит байтовые последовательности, но делает он это странно. Пришлось отделить \x00 от 6build, чтобы последовательность была воспринята корректно.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский что значит "фиг знает"? Я же вам написал: строки должны заканчиваться нулевым байтом! \x00 - это нулевой байт!

Comment: Не, я про то, что последовательность \x006b воспринималась как единый символ "k", хотя должна была представлять из себя нулевой байт и "6b" :)

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский а вот это уже интереснее: что такое `\x..`? Это ничто иное как шестнадцатиричное число, а `\x006b` - это вполне валидное шестнадцатиричное число, которое меньше `\xFF` и может быть отображено в `cstring`. Как этого избежать? Разделить строку: `"\x00""6b"`.